# WriteStream nodejs out memory

Tags: node.js, stream, createwritestream

I try to create a 20MB file, but it throws the error out of memory, set the max-old-space-size to 2gb, but still can someone explain to me why writing a 20mb stream consumes so much memory?

I have 2.3 g.b of free memory

```
let size=20*1024*1024; //20MB

for(let i=0;i<size;i++){
     writeStream.write('A')
}
writeStream.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering), `Writable` stores data in an internal buffer. The amount of data that can be buffered depends on `highWaterMark` option passed into the stream's constructor.

As long as size of buffered data is below below `highWaterMark`, calls to `Writable.write(chunk)` will return `true`. Once the buffered data exceeds limit specified by `highWaterMark` it returns `false`. This is when you should stop writing more data to `Writable` and wait for `drain` event which indicates that it's now appropriate to resume writing data.

Your program crashes because it keeps writing even when the internal buffer has exceeded `highWaterMark`.

Check the docs about [`Event:'drain'`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain). It includes an example program.

---

This looks like a nice use case for [`Readable.pipe(Writable)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)
You can create a generator function that returns a character and then create a `Readable` from that generator by using `Readable.from()`. Then pipe the output of `Readable` to a `Writable` file.

The reason why it's beneficial to use pipe here is that :

> A key goal of the stream API, particularly the stream.pipe() method,
> is to limit the buffering of data to acceptable levels such that
> sources and destinations of differing speeds will not overwhelm the
> available memory. [link](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering)

and

> The flow of data will be automatically managed so that the destination
> Writable stream is not overwhelmed by a faster Readable stream. [link](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');

const size = 20 * 1024 * 1024; //20MB

function * generator(numberOfChars) {
    while(numberOfChars--) {
        yield 'A';
    }
}

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt');
const readable = Readable.from(generator(size));

readable.pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me, my question is only because the first way fails, in the documentation they recommend using a stream.once ('Drain'), to restore the writing of the stream, I see that sending the data asynchronously would also work,

Comment: @KevinMendoza, I just edited my answer to explain why your program failed.

Comment: In short, data is written faster in the buffer, what is it capable of emptying? and that's why it fails.

Comment: @KevinMendoza, when you transfer data from one stream to another, If the sender is faster than receiver, the sent data has to be stored somewhere temporarily. this temporary storage is buffer. So I don't think it's to speed up the process but to sync the sender and receivers of varying bandwidth.